# Can I find the length of an right angle triangle, from one side and two angles?

Tags: trigonometry

In my c++ application I have a 3d plane, with a point above it. The plane is rotated, and the point is at 0,0,0.

In the image below, the plane is represented by the triangle side B - C. (S3)

A is the point that is at zero. 
B is the mid-point of the plane.

What I need to calculate is the distance from Point A, to where it intersects the plane (Point C).

I know the angle of the plane, and the coordinates of point A and Point B.

Point A is at (xyz) 0,0,0;
Point B is at: -1,2.7,-19.7;

From this, i know the length of Side S2 (19.7).
The angle of Angle B is 17.675 degrees.

So I now have one side and one angle. I know that the corner at point C is 90 degrees. Is this enough to get me the length of the  the side S1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can, indeed recall that

- $S_3=S_2 \cos B$
- $S_1=S_2 \sin B$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What would this look like as a single equation? My math is very rusty.

Comment: @anti Yes of course to find S1 you need to calculate $$S_1=S_2 \cdot \sin B$$ take a look here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=19.7*sin(17.675%C2%B0)

Comment: Thank you for your time, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: @anti You are welcome! Bye

Comment: ..Hi again, sorry to bring this back.. Should the angle for this approach be degrees? Or radians?

Comment: @anti The angle you heve indicated is  17.675 degrees. You must pay attention that your calculator is setted in degreeswhen you take sin(17.675), Otherwise you could convert in radians by  $\pi\cdot(17.675/180)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the right triangle is uniquely determined by its hypotenuse  and  an angle $\alpha.$

The other two sides are $$ BC=AB cos(  \alpha) \\AC= AB sin( \alpha)$$